# How to create dynamic <div>s with multiple inputs based on the value selected in the range slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create dynamic div with 3 cells on each div. Above that is a range slider with 2 inputs on each end. The range consists of values between 36-50 and there are 8 div for each even value between the range like 36, 38, 40.. and so on. If the range selected is between 36-40, then only 3 div's must be displayed and if selected between 36-48, then 7 div's must be displayed. And the values of the selected range needs be displayed in the first readonly input cell.

This is how it looks like now

[image]

Range slider

```
<h5><span class="badge badge-light">Select Size Range:</span></h5>
<form>
<div class="row">
<div class="col"><input type="text" class="value form-control" data- 
index="36" value="36" /></div>
<div class="col-10" id="slider"></div>
<div class="col"><input type="text" class="value form-control" data- 
index="50" value="50" /></div>
</div></form>
```

Script for the slider

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').slider({
min: 36,
max:50,
step: 1,
values: [36, 50],
range: true,
slide: function(event, ui) {
  $.each(ui.values, function(i, v) {
    $('input.value').eq(i).val(v);
  });
}
});
$('input.value').change(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$('#slider').slider('values', $this.attr('data-index'), $this.val());
});
});
```

CSS for the slider

```
<style>
#slider {
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: black;}
#slider div.ui-slider-range {
background: transparent;}
input[data-index="1"] {float: right;}</style>
```

Value entered in this input is reflected in all other cells

```
<div  class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
<h5><span class="badge badge-dark">Add Quantity:</span></h5>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync()">
</div></div>
```

Script to reflect data in all cells

```
function sync()
{
var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
var n3 = document.getElementById('n3');
var n4 = document.getElementById('n4');
var n5 = document.getElementById('n5');
var n6 = document.getElementById('n6');
var n7 = document.getElementById('n7');
var n8 = document.getElementById('n8');
var n9 = document.getElementById('n9');
n9.value = n8.value = n7.value = n6.value = n5.value = n4.value = n3.value 
= n2.value = n1.value;}
```

div with 3 cells that needs to be generated dynamically, with maximum 8 possible divs. The value in the range(36,38...) is to be displayed in the readonly cell.

```
<form action="add.php" method="GET">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="36" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="38" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n3" id="n3"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="40" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n4" id="n4"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="42" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n5" id="n5"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="44" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n6" id="n6"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="46" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n7" id="n7"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="48" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n8" id="n8"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm">
<input type="text" value="50" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="n9" id="n9"/><br>
<select class="form-control">
<option>25%</option>
<option>50%</option>
<option>100%</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

how to loop the divs based on the values entered in the range slider?

Comment: Your question is not informative, make it clear

Comment: Kindly check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this problem by selecting all of the `<div>` that you want to show/hide. Then check each of the `<input>`'s readOnly value to see whether the value lies between the slider values. And use jQuery to show/hide them accordingly.

To select all the `<div>` of interest, add a class to them first.

```
<div class="col-sm show-hide">
    <input type="text" value="36" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" class="form-control"><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="n2" id="n2" /><br>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>25%</option>
        <option>50%</option>
        <option>100%</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Notice I added a class `show-hide` to the `<div>`

Then we can select them like this:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    min: 36,
    max: 50,
    step: 1,
    values: [36, 50],
    range: true,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        // select the divs
        $('.show-hide').each(function (idx, div) {
            var $div = $(div);

            // get the readonly value of the input inside the div
            var value = $div.children().first().val();

            // check whether the value lies between the values specified by the slider
            if (value < ui.values[0] || value > ui.values[1]) {
                $div.hide();
            } else {
                $div.show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. This is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can automatically assign '0' to the editable textboxes of the <div>'s that have been hidden?

Comment: You can add a line `$div.find('input:nth-of-type(2)').val('0');` right above the `$div.hide()` to set the editable hidden input's value to '0'. If you want to remove the '0' when the inputs shows up, add another line `$div.find('input:nth-of-type(2)').val('');` right above `$div.show();`

Comment: The concept behind is selecting the elements you are interested in, and then do some operations on the elements. The `.val('0')` sets the value of the input to '0'. `.val` is used to set a value here. Also, `.val` can also be used to read value from the element. If no argument is passed to `.val()`, the operation would be getting the value from the element instead of setting a value for it. Just like the line `var value = $div.children().first().val();` did. Hope it helps. You can read more from [jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)